# How create the timeline with train status on travel?

Tags: graph, echarts

I would create this graph, the only timeline, (with eCharts library) when see the train status by stations. Whether it stopped at that station or still has to arrive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kClqY.png)

Comment: could you please tell us more about what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have solved the partial solution but i have problem how to color the lines from 2002 to 2004 or 2006 it green and the rest with gray.
You can see this post on github:
[link](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/10745)

Comment: The solutions is [link](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xwsyY9DhLb&v=2)